# OPTIMIZE FOR variable error

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I'm having a problem specifying a value within an `OPTIMIZE FOR` statement. I'd like to optimize the query with the value as a string, but I must be doing something wrong, because SQL gives the following error:

> The value specified for the variable "@test" in the OPTIMIZE FOR
>   clause could not be implicitly converted to that variable's type.

The example below is slightly contrived but the problem is the same as the one I'm having with my actual query.

```sql
declare @TEMP table(asWord nvarchar(max), asNumber int)

insert into @TEMP (asWord, asNumber) values (
    'one',
    1
), (
    'two',
    2
)

DECLARE @test nvarchar(max)
SET @test = 'one'

select * from @TEMP
where asWord = @test
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@test = 'one'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is because you are declaring your `@test` variable as `nvarchar(max)` and comparing that to a non lob literal in the `OPTIMIZE FOR` clause.**

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) on `OPTIMIZE FOR` :

```
OPTIMIZE FOR ( _@variable\_name_ { UNKNOWN | = literal_constant } [ , ...n ] )
```

You should change the length of the variable  to the size of the highest possible character length of the value that will be stored in it.

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(3);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7537604a5676ca0b43bd53e77e979af)

---

**`NVARCHAR(MAX)`  and `OPTIMIZE FOR`**

In theory you are able to optimize for `nvarchar(max)` fields, but it appears that the literal has to be over `4000` (for `nvarchar`) characters long:

When creating 4000 spaces:

```
SELECT REPLICATE(' ', 4000);
```

And adding them to the end of the constant:

```
declare @TEMP table(asWord nvarchar(max), asNumber int)

insert into @TEMP (asWord, asNumber) values (
    'one',
    1
), (
    'two',
    2
)

DECLARE @test nvarchar(max)
SET @test = 'one'

select * from @TEMP
where asWord = @test
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@test  = N'one                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ' ))
```

It works too.

You cannot use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` to explicitly change the constant to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`
[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8b034135e1325384f8a5844215f19c6)

**Extra**

---

If the variable is lower than `nvarchar(max)` but the constant is over `4000` (for `nvarchar`) characters, it still works.:

```
declare @TEMP table(asWord nvarchar(max), asNumber int)

insert into @TEMP (asWord, asNumber) values (
    'one',
    1
), (
    'two',
    2
)

DECLARE @test nvarchar(3)
SET @test = 'one'

select * from @TEMP
where asWord = @test
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@test  = N'one                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ' ))
```

Because all the spaces after the literal value are 'cut off' and it is treated as a nvarchar(3):

```
<ColumnReference Column="@test" ParameterCompiledValue="N'one'" ParameterRuntimeValue="N'one'" />
```

If we change the variable to `nvarchar(4)`

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(4)
```

One more space is present in the `ParameterCompiledValue`

```
<ColumnReference Column="@test" ParameterCompiledValue="N'one '" ParameterRuntimeValue="N'one'" />
```

Comment: Anything up to 8000 bytes (so, `nvarchar(4000)`) should be fine